# c++ passing string to varargs

Tags: c++, string

```
#define LOG(format,...) Logger::Log(format,__VA_ARGS__)
#define STRIP(netIp) GeneralUtils::inet_ntop_(netIp)
string GeneralUtils::inet_ntop_(unsigned int netIp){
    char strIP[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
    in_addr sin_addr;
    sin_addr.s_addr = netIp;
    inet_ntop(AF_INET, &sin_addr.s_addr, strIP, sizeof strIP);
    return string(strIP);
}
```

when calling to :

```
LOG("src %s dst %s" ,STRIP(src_ip_));
```

i get compilation error:

```
cannot pass objects of non-trivially-copyable type ‘std::string {aka struct std::basic_string<char>}’ through ‘...’
```

I understand that varargs is c compatible , so i cannot send string to it.
Is there a simple way to bypass it?
Will it be correct to fix it like this:

```
#define STRIP(netIp) GeneralUtils::inet_ntop_(netIp).data()
```

Comment: Instead of using `data` (or `c_str`) in the `STRIP` macro, you could use it in the `LOG` call: `LOG("src %s dst %s" ,STRIP(src_ip_).c_str());`

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg i preffer to fix one place and not all placed that call to LOG

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#define STRIP(netIp) GeneralUtils::inet_ntop_(netIp).data()
```

is **wrong**, it will invoke undefined behavior since it doesn't include a terminating zero. Use

```
#define STRIP(netIp) GeneralUtils::inet_ntop_(netIp).c_str()
```

instead.

Comment: can you please explain 'undefined behavior' , i didnt expreince any problem when i change to inet_ntop_(netIp).data()

Comment: @user1495181 the `%s` format specifier expects a zero-terminated C string. `std::string.data()` returns a non-zero terminated C string, which ***will*** crash some day, that's why you ***must*** use `c_str()`.

Comment: My code is full with format %s and data() as return and i never crash on this. can you please explain in which conditions i will crash.

Comment: @user1495181 nobody knows that.

Comment: @user1495181 please let me know which application is this so that I can avoid using it...

Comment: i dont argue with you.  I love to know the underline of the things. i dont love the term randomly crash, because even randomly crash means certain conditions that lead to crash, so i just wonder what are the conditions.

Comment: @user1495181 1. thanks for the accept. 2. Really, when there's undefined behavior, you can't predict what and when will crash, because it depends on a lot of things which are not to be relied upon.

Comment: @AvihaiMarchiano The problem is that the crash will occur when some random garbage in memory causes the string returned by data() to NOT be properly terminated with a null character.  Because it's random garbage in memory, left behind by who knows what combination of programs, it cannot be precisely predicted.  One can only recognize the possibility, and allow for it by using c_str(), which will return a null terminated string.  See the [definition of data()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/data/). "_...no guarantees that a null character terminates the character sequence..._"

Comment: _"`std::string.data()` returns a non-zero terminated C string"_ This is incorrect. In C++03 `data()` returns a string which is not guaranteed to be zero-terminated, but in practice all known implementations define it identically to `c_str()`. In C++11 it is **required** to be identical to `c_str()`. So in fact the code will not crash one day because it used `data()`.

Answer (score 5):

You can pass `const char *` instead of `std::string`. You can take it from `std::string` by calling `c_str()`

Comment: In this way all calls to log need to have an ugly .c_str(). i think it better to define this in one place